# How to generate Custom Url Scheme in IONIC 5 (cordova) for android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic5, custom-url

I want a link which on Click should open a specific page of my Ionic Cordova App(Android),
For which i need to create and implement "Custom URL Scheme"